# Can we declare functions inside functions?

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   void foo();
   printf("1 ");
   foo();
}

void foo()
{
    printf("2 ");
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
```

How declaring functions inside functions work?
Does it mean that foo() function can only be called by main()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can *declare*, but you cannot *define*. Also, you can declare function as many times you want, but define only once.

Comment: Is the declaration public?

Comment: The declaration you have now is only visible inside `main`.  If you attempted to call `foo` from another top-level function placed *in between* your `main` and `foo` functions, you would get an error.

Comment: @PankajMahato Well, context is different. Public/Private and declaration are completely different things.

Comment: @zwol what is top-level functions. can you explain or give some links

Answer (score 0):

***We can declare a function inside a function***, but it's not a nested function. Because nested function definitions can not access local variables of the surrounding blocks, they can access only the containing module's global variables.
So it is better to declare any function above the main function so that you can call them anywhere in any function.